# Typewriter effect with dynamic content

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a typewriter effect on a banner text once this element comes in the viewport. I almost got it to work, but I still have some problems I can't seem to solve myself:

- when the typewriter effect is playing, the last character is not showing (I found this code online)
- when I detect if the element is in the viewport, my typewriter-animations keeps flashing

I'm using ACF to get the content.
I also tried to rewrite the code to jquery, but that doesn't seem to work too.

HTML/PHP

```
echo '<div class="contentBlock featured bg-black">';
    echo '<div class="textWrapper">';
        echo '<h2 id="original" style="display:none;">'. get_sub_field('grote_titel') .'</h2>';
        echo '<h2 id="typewriter"></h2>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

**jquery/js**

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
    $('.contentBlock.featured').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).isInViewport()) {
            var str = document.getElementById('original').innerText,
                i = 0,
                isTag,
                text;

            (function type() {
                text = str.slice(0, ++i);
                if (text === str) return;

                document.getElementById('typewriter').innerHTML = text;

                var char = text.slice(-1);
                if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
                if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;
                
                if (isTag) return type();
                setTimeout(type, 80);
            }());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: *the last character is not showing* - add another character to your string before you start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first problem just do the test in first:

```
  (function type() {
    if (text === str) return;
    text = str.slice(0, ++i);
```

for the flashing you execute the typewriter each time you scroll and the title is on viewport. its normal.. to avoid flashing , you have 2 solutions :

1. you could just increase a little the speed of typewriter to 40 for example (not the best)
2. you avoid to relaunch the typing while it is active -> play with a boolean (this solution in snippet)

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

var typing = false;
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
    $('.contentBlock.featured').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).isInViewport() && !typing) {
            typing = true;
            var str = document.getElementById('original').innerText,
                i = 0,
                isTag,
                text;

            (function type() {
                if (text === str) {typing= false;return;}
                text = str.slice(0, ++i);


                document.getElementById('typewriter').innerHTML = text;

                var char = text.slice(-1);
                if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
                if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;
                
                if (isTag) return type();
                setTimeout(type, 80);
            }());
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentBlock featured bg-black">
  <div class="textWrapper">
    <h2 id="original" style="display:none;">Big Title ttttttttx</h2>
    <h2 id="typewriter"></h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="just text to create scroll">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br>the td's are not updated when you select td, its the reason you have older values, i dont see event about that, so i suggest you to wait the value of tds are changed by testing the month, you could add year if needed:

  </div>  
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!
I make one more change and added another boolean to make sure the animation only plays once. Now the animation repeats after it's completely done and you scroll through the page again.